# Great resources in F# for beginners use and examples for business

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, f#, functional-programming

Are there some links to great resources for F# for:

1. Beginners use.
2. Examples in applying it to business and enterprise applications.

What I meant by great is similar to the videos presented in the Learn section of ASP.NET and WindowsClient.net.

Thanks.

Comment: There are already quite a few resources and links to resources here - just remember to search for "[F#] keyword" rather than "F# keyword"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a beginner, the best place to start is by watching this **[video by Luca Bolognese](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/)**, the F# program manager. Then, start watching these series of **[videos and tutorials](http://tomasp.net/articles/fsharp-webcast-functional.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading the book "Functional Programming for the Real World" by Tomas Petricek with Jon Skeet. It will guide you from the basics to practical real world problems and their solutions in F#.

http://www.manning.com/petricek/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [F Sharp Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming) on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Main_Page) is the best resource to start with. It is brief, tutorial-like overview. For more in-depth reading about certain facettes I would suggest [Expert F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598504) by Don Syme himself.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/206/f.aspx its  a great resource centre for F#